# How to find children of an XML element with a given attribute?

Tags: python, xml, svg, elementtree

What is wrong with this search term (using ElementTree)?

```
matches = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g[@id='" + sid + "']/circle")
```

I get no matches. The element in question certainly has a 'circle' child and this works fine (without circle):

```
matches = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g[@id='" + sid + "']")
```

With the above I'll get a match. I'm following the advice [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) (see the examples section). My example is almost no different to this example

```
root.findall(".//*[@name='Singapore']/year")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Silly mistake, these are SVG elements, the solution is as follows:

```
matches = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g[@id='" + sid + "']/{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}circle")
```